# See who modify the files on a Google drive folder

Tags: google-docs, google-drive-shared-drive

My prof asked the final project to be uploaded on his gdrive shared file. I already uploaded it, but weeks later my prof informed me that I have not upload my files.

I suspect there was someone who removed my files from the shared file. I know you can see in the info in view details on the right-hand side. But, my prof already hide the folder, so when I clicked on the folder links, it requires access. It also not displayed on my gdrive dashboard, so I cannot perform 'view ddetails' on the folder.

My prof is kinda dumb with technology and insist it was my fault and won't hear my explanation that I can see who removed my files by granting the file access once again. So, I want to access this file only to defend myself that I am not "guilty".

1. Is there any way to see the activity on that folder? Because I need an access and my prof adamant that he won't give me access
2. When I access the folder link, it ask me for access. Is that because I do not have a file on that folder now?
3. Is someone who still have their files on the folder still can access the folder? If so, I can borrow my friend's account to see if there was any changes on the folder

Thanks in advance. I appreciated any help T.T

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you could use the option of "Drive activity", some of the changes you will be able to see are the following:
Edits or comments in Google Docs
Renames a file or folder
Moves or removes a file or folder
Uploads a new file to a folder
Shares or unshares an item

You can find the description of the feature here: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2409045

I hope it can be of help :D

P.S: Good luck with your prof